# Authorize specific nodes - Allow connections from a sub-node "Charlie"

Tags: substrate-node-template

I am following the Get Started tutorials "Authorize specific nodes".
I'm always waiting when I add charlie nodes

```
sudo.sudo
Authenticates the sudo key and dispatches a function call with Root origin. 
call: Call
nodeAuthorization.addWellKnownNode
node: OpaquePeerId
<空的>
owner: MultiAddress
{
  Id: 5FLSigC9HGRKVhB9FiEo4Y3koPsNmBmLJbpXg2mp1hXcS59Y
}
signature
0xf2e4af6420cf22d6f323495bcc23eddd2299d4906ab97313003c81007cb9b01421557fdf866d206eaa976d0f9cb73540c42006c833a0c36a9f0a50518183258a

交易哈希
0xe03c82c76b6b13ac9b91eae748fd2a408ed3a86a9401e0da0d0c08e31adcebaf

生命周期
存在的，有效期从#0 到 #64
#/extrinsics/decode/0xcd028400d43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d01f2e4af6420cf22d6f323495bcc23eddd2299d4906ab97313003c81007cb9b01421557fdf866d206eaa976d0f9cb73540c42006c833a0c36a9f0a50518183258a050000000700090098002408011220876a7b4984f98006dc8d666e28b60de307309835d775e7755cc770328cdacf2e0090b5ab205c6974c9ea841be688864633dc9ca8a357843eeacf2314649965fe22
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: To add Charlie as a sub-node, follow the steps outlined here: https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/get-started/authorize-specific-nodes/#launch-network-nodes